# MYSQL ORDER BY Number in string

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-order-by

I have data in my table as follows. But I can't sort because the numbers are at the end of the string.

Only 4-digit year information is available at the end of users

I want to sort by the years at the end of the articles, is it possible?

```
Users column

USER-A-2021
USER-B-2018
USER-C-2019
USER-D-2017
USER-E-2020
USER-F-2016
```

Comment: select * from [tablename] order by right(Users,4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this using `RIGHT(str,len)`

> `RIGHT` - Returns the rightmost len characters from the string str, or
> NULL if any argument is NULL.

```
SELECT *
FROM data
ORDER BY RIGHT(info, 4)

CREATE TABLE data (
 info varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO data VALUES
('USER-A-2021'),
('USER-B-2018'),
('USER-C-2019'),
('USER-D-2017'),
('USER-E-2020'),
('USER-F-2016');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select *from Users order by right(UserId,4) asc;
```